# How does the value event work on updates with Firebase listeners?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Do event listeners guarantee that all data ever written to a path will be delivered to the client eventually? 
For instance if I have a game client that pushes moves to the same path one after the other will the listening client receive all updates?
What would happen in this situation: client A pushes move 1 to game1/user1/move_data which client B is listening on; client A then immediately pushes another move updating the value at game1/user1/move_data. 
Will the listening client be guaranteed to receive all moves pushed?

Currently I have a system that creates a new path per move and then I am calling single listeners on each move as each client reaches that move in it's state. It doesn't seem efficient as if the client A receives the most recent move that client B has made then client A begins listening on a path that doesn't exist yet.

The below quotes are from this link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data

"The value event is used to read a static snapshot of the contents at a given database path, as they existed at the time of the read event. It is triggered once with the initial data and again every time the data changes. The event callback is passed a snapshot containing all data at that location, including child data. In the code example above, value returned all of the blog posts in your app. Everytime a new blog post is added, the callback function will return all of the posts."

The part about as they existed at the time of the read event causes me to think that if a listener is on a path then the client will receive all values ever on that path eventually.

There is also this line from the guarantees section which I am struggling to decipher:

"Value events are always triggered last and are guaranteed to contain updates from any other events which occurred before that snapshot was taken."

I am working with a language that does not have a Google based sdk and am asking this question, so I can further assess Firebases' suitability for my uses.

Comment: I ran some tests and it does seem to be the case that all updates are received on the client. I'm not posting an answer, because I don't know why that's the case. Is it the same if a connection is lost? Does Google pass the previous value before the update along to another worker if somebody is listening on that path or multiple clients are listening on that path and they become disconnected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Realtime Database performs **state synchronization**. If a client is listening to data in a location, it will receive the state of that data. If there are changes in the data, it will receive the latest state of that data.

> ...if I have a game client that pushes moves to the same path one after the other will the listening client receive all updates?

If there are multiple updates before the Firebase server has a chance to send the state to a listener, it may skip some intermediate values. So there is no guarantee that your client will see every state change, there is just a guarantee that it will eventually see the latest state.

If you want to ensure that all clients (can) see all state changes, you should store the state changes themselves in the database.

Answer (score 0):

try to this code to get update value from firebase database:-

```
 mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mFirebaseDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference();

    mFirebaseDatabase.child("new_title").setValue("Realtime Database");
    mFirebaseDatabase.child("new_title").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String appTitle = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
            Log.e("Hey", appTitle);
            title.setText(appTitle);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.e("Hey", "Failed to read app title value.", error.toException());
        }
    });
```

Comment: This does not answer concerns about reliability of event notification/state transfer.

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32565377)